# Selenium+BS, Scraping: issue extracting text from <script type=application/ld+json>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

UPDATE: I fixed a few syntax errors ( I was unable to run script because I made too many requests in short time, so I was afraid to run again ). Code is updated now, but the problem still exists.

I am quite new to webscraping. Right now, I am attempting to generate real addresses with fake identities so that I can create data for my mysql database. I need this test data to move forward with this project.

NOTE: The data will not be used beyond testing.

I am essentially trying to generate several addresses per zipcode. I started off with merely trying to use requests and beautiful soup libraries to scrape the zillow website for addresses based on zipcodes.

The problem is that, once I have used beautiful soup to select a script object in the form

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {"@type":"SingleFamilyResidence","@context":"http://schema.org","name":"6012 Briscoe Ln, Louisville, KY 40228","floorSize":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","@context":"http://schema.org","value":"1,555"},"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","@context":"http://schema.org","streetAddress":"6012 Briscoe Ln ","addressLocality":"Louisville","addressRegion":"KY","postalCode":"40228"},"geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","@context":"http://schema.org","latitude":38.14154,"longitude":-85.648248},"url":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/6012-Briscoe-Ln-Louisville-KY-40228/73554517_zpid/"}</script>
```

I get an empty string upon using the `.text` attribute, so when I go to load it as json to get the dictionary stored between the script tags, I get an error stating that a value was expected.

The input `zips.csv` file comes in the format of a csv.

filename: `zips.csv` 40223,40214,40228,40219,40241,40206,40220,40212,40206,40210,40213,40203,40213,40208,40272,40220,40222

It is one line, with each zipcode separated by a comma (as noted by csv).

Here is my code to demonstrate what I am doing; The website (listed as baseUrl in code) is what I am interested in. I append the zipcode to the url to get the page of homes in that zipcode. Even when I use `test` I  as source to `BeautifulSoup` constructor I receive the same result. If you comment lines with `# D` and uncomment the alternative `source` and `homes`, you can see this.

```
def configure_driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    #chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    return driver 

def gen_searchers(driver):
    print('gen searchers')

    baseUrl2 = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/"
    selector2 = ".photo-cards"

    driver.get(baseUrl2) # D

    # sometimes captcha pops up, so get around quick polling
    WebDriverWait(driver,115).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_css_selector(selector2)) # D

    # wait for housing list to load
    zips = []
    addy_all_zips = []

    try: 
        with open('zips.csv','r') as file:
            zips = file.readline().split(',')
    except:
        print('file not found\n')
    else:
        # for each zipcode in zips
        for z in zips:
            mainUrl2 = baseUrl2 + z +'_rb/'

            # scrape web dom
            driver.get(mainUrl2) #D
            try: 
                WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(lambda s: s.find_element_by_css_selector(selector2)) #D

                addy_one_zip = [] 
                source = driver.page_source #D
                #source = '<script type="application/ld+json">{"@type":"SingleFamilyResidence","@context":"http://schema.org","name":"6012 Briscoe Ln, Louisville, KY 40228","floorSize":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","@context":"http://schema.org","value":"1,555"},"address":{"@type":"PostalAddress","@context":"http://schema.org","streetAddress":"6012 Briscoe Ln ","addressLocality":"Louisville","addressRegion":"KY","postalCode":"40228"},"geo":{"@type":"GeoCoordinates","@context":"http://schema.org","latitude":38.14154,"longitude":-85.648248},"url":"https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/6012-Briscoe-Ln-Louisville-KY-40228/73554517_zpid/"}</script>'
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
                homes_list = soup.select_one("ul.photo-cards > li") #D
                homes = homes_list.select_one("script[type='application/ld+json']") #D

                # homes = soup.find("script",{"type": "application/ld+json"})
                print(homes) # PRINTS <script ....> ... </script>
                print(homes.text) # PRINTS string with no text
                print()

                # write data out and look at format
                with open("testpage.html", 'w') as file:
                    file.write(str(homes))
                    print('written')

                # ERROR ON THIS LINE (LOADING)
                js = json.loads(homes.text) 


                # TO PREVENT LOADING PAGES FOR EACH ZIP, JUST TRY ON ONE
                break
            except TimeoutException as err:
                print(err)
```

I really am not sure of the issue. When I research my issue, I find information on how to extract text between script tags (where type is ld json), but I am unsuccessful, despite having replicated what others have done and having the proper script tag to perform operation on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do if you are not blocked by that site already. I've used `40223` as a demo which ultimately form this url `https://www.zillow.com/homes/40223_rb/`:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.zillow.com/homes/40223_rb/"

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for homes in soup.select("script[type='application/ld+json']"):
    home_url = json.loads(homes.get_text(strip=True))['url']
    print(home_url)
```

First few results are like:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/9903-Windfall-Trce-Louisville-KY-40223/73495241_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2001-Ben-Ali-Rd-Louisville-KY-40223/73476052_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/321-Piatt-Pl-UNIT-102-Louisville-KY-40223/2079132587_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/community/enclave-at-douglass-hills/2085942117_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/community/enclave-at-douglass-hills/2085942119_zpid/
https://www.zillow.com/community/enclave-at-douglass-hills/2085942118_zpid/
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try. When I used requests, I was get caught on captchas, that is why I switched to a headed chromedriver in selenium. Interesting that you made it around that as well, which simplifies some things.

Comment: for some reason, when I run the code you have above in a new script, soup.select("script[type='application/ld+json']") returns [], even though res.status_code is 200. @SIM

Comment: What about `res.url`?

Comment: It returns a link to a captcha. I am not sure how you got around the captcha. This is why I switched to selenium (and also because I though maybe I needed to give page time to generate html before scraping)

Comment: It allows few requests and that is the reason I didn't encounter that captcha.